# WPF ListBox using ItemsSource and ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I'm confused as to how bindings are resolved when I have both an `ItemsSource` and an `ItemTemplate` in a WPF `ListBox`.

I have an `ObservableCollection<int>` called `ListOfIndexes`. For each index, I want to look up its record in a database table. I hope to do that in the `IndexToObjectDescriptionConverter`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfIndexes}" 
         ItemTemplate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IndexToObjectDescriptionConverter}}" />
```

But a breakpoint in the converter is telling me that the value being read in by the `ItemTemplate` binding is of the window itself — i.e., the `DataContext` of the `ItemsSource` and `ItemsTemplate` is the same.

Pardon a bit of candidness, but this seems DUMB. The entire point of the `ItemTemplate` is to render each element within the `ItemsSource`, so I guess I figured that the `DataContext` of the `ItemTemplate` would be the individual element being rendered.

So, that said, how do I tell the `ItemTemplate` that it should worry about the individual elements represented by the `ItemsSource` and not use the entire window's `DataContext`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a data template for the ItemTemplate.  This is then applied to each item in the list

MSDN docs are here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The issue her is about data context scope.  When you bind any property on the ListBox, it will use the data context of the ListBox - hence why that data context is being passed to the converter.  If you set a data template inside the ItemTemplate, it will apply that template to each item in the list.  I guess based on the simple code you've provided you would need to have the converter inside the data template:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfIndexes}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IndexToObjectDescriptionConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In this case, the ContentControl will be rendered for each item, with that item as it's data context.

Comment: Perfect. I guess I didn't realize that a `DataTemplate` within an `ItemTemplate` properly identifies the data context, whereas just definding a binding with an `ItemTemplate` uses the control's scope. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd advise that you have a good read of the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page in MSDN so that you can get a better understanding of this data binding process.

> *I want to look up its record in a database table. I hope to do that in the IndexToObjectDescriptionConverter.*

That is your first mistake. An `IValueConverter` is responsible for converting data bound values, *not* accessing databases. Access your data in your view model and populate public properties with the results. Then data bind those properties to UI controls in the XAML.

> *Pardon a bit of candidness, but this seems DUMB*

Only to those that do not understand the situation.

> *how do I tell the ItemTemplate that it should worry about the individual elements represented by the ItemsSource and not use the entire window's DataContext?*

You don't tell it anything... simply defining the correct XAML is enough:

In `Resources`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SomeDataTemplate">
    <!-- The DataContext here is set to an item from the data bound collection -->
</DataTemplate>
```

In XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfIndexes}" 
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeDataTemplate}" />
```

That's it.