# How do I drag n drop files into a ListBox with it showing the file path?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, drag-and-drop, listbox

Currently when I drag n drop files into my ListBox using the `Window_Drop` event I have this code.

```
string[] files = (string[]) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true);
listBox.Items.Add(files);
```

Which works fine in WinForm it prints out the path of the file I just dragged and dropped into it as a item to the ListBox.

However when I do the same thing in WPF I get this

> String[] Array

as an output instead of the path.

Now I know that code from WinForm doesn't exactly transfer over to WPF but I would guess it's pretty similar?

How do I correctly drag and drop an item to the ListBox with it showing the path of the file?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the `string[]` to the ListBox you will need to add a string from a specified index of the array like this `listBox.Items.Add(files[yourIndex]);`

EDIT: If you're going to import multiple files at once without adding more from the same array you should do:

```
foreach(string path in files)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the ItemsSource property of the ListBox to your string[]:

```
string[] files = (string[]) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true);
listBox.ItemsSource = files;
```

In WPF you typically bind the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl (such as a ListBox) to an IEnumerable<T> and define an ItemTemplate in your XAML markup that defines the appearance of each object of type T:

[WPF ListBox using ItemsSource and ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411699/wpf-listbox-using-itemssource-and-itemtemplate)

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Green" FontSize="16" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```