# Iterate Over Media Files Properties And Display Filenames into Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm writing a simple WinForms application which I will use prior to when I edit my video footage in order to know the total length of all the video files when combined and "*edited*".

So ideally, I load them up then get the duration of each video and tally them up.

However I get stuck in terms of which collection class to use since I am using an external library `IWMPMedia` in addition to `WindowsMediaPlayer` to get the filenames and duration.

When I use a string array to get the filename, I get the whole path, which is something I don't want. Please see the following code snippet:

```
 using WMPLib;

 public partial class frmBacklinkMediaSerializer : Form
 {
    WindowsMediaPlayer wmp;
    IWMPMedia mediainfo;

    Double Duration(String file)
    {
        wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
        mediainfo = wmp.newMedia(file);
        return mediainfo.duration;
    }

    void callDialogBox()
    {
        OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        theDialog.Filter = "MP4 Videos (*.mp4)|*.mp4";
        theDialog.FilterIndex = 0;
        theDialog.Multiselect = true;
        DialogResult result = theDialog.ShowDialog();
        string[] selected = theDialog.FileNames;
        string strFilename = theDialog.FileName;

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(strFilename);
            string temp = Duration(strFilename).ToString();
            TimeSpan conversion = 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration(strFilename));
            if (strFilename != null || strFilename.Length != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("My file names are below: " + "\n\n" + mediainfo.name + "\n\n" + "My file duration is: " + conversion.ToString(), "Video Properties", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);                  
            }
        }
    }

    //I then call callDialogBox() on a button click event
```

The output shows as per the below screenshot:

[image]

I want to be able to select multiple files and show the in the listbox but I get a:

> Additional information: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.

When adding items to the listbox.

So two problems:

**1.** Being able to select and list filenames below one another

**2.** List the filenames in the listbox

With regards to point **1.** , the below code snippet does somewhat achieve it but gives me the entire filename..

`string[] selected = theDialog.FileNames;
  foreach(string items in selected)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Here are your filenames: " + items);
  }`

Gives me the entire path. Read up on some resources online but I can't seem to get what I want.

I had a look at: [How do I drag n drop files into a ListBox with it showing the file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323730/how-do-i-drag-n-drop-files-into-a-listbox-with-it-showing-the-file-path) and it didn't do the trick.

Comment: You want to list all the selected filenames in a listBox?

Comment: @Abhishek **And** sum up their durations.

Comment: Where do you have to show the sum of the durations?

Comment: @Abhishek A label, message box, anything.. not really fussy about that part

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to add the filenames to the ListBox:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(selected);
```

Once this is done, you can then display your total duration.

Edit:
To list only file names, use following line.

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(selected.Select(o=>System.IO.Path.GetFileName(o)).ToArray());
```

Comment: As explicitly mentioned in the question that the string array selected returns the filenames with their paths and I don't want the path section of the filename.

Comment: @Harold_Finch: Hi Harold. I have edited the answer. Hope this is what you wanted.